# Getting line breaks in a contact form text area to appear in an email

Tags: html, forms, textarea

We are currently creating a contact form - how would it be possible to reproduce line breaks in a textarea in the email sent by the contact form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What server-side program are you using to send mail?

Comment: Can you elaborate, with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your textarea content into <pre> element and define proper font for it in CSS:

```
<pre>content-of-your-textarea-goes-here</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options -- first, use c-smile's answer; all webmail clients and *most* if not all desktop clients should render `<pre>` tags properly.

Your other option is to parse the submitted text-area's text and turn newlines into `<br>` tags.  If you want to be *really* nice about it you can change on `\n` into a `<br>` tag and two newlines in a row into a `<p>` tag.

```
This is a message.

With multiple paragraph-like structures.
```

would become either:

```
This is a message.<br>
<br>
With multiple paragraph-like structures.
```

or

```
<p>This is a message.</p>

<p>With multiple paragraph-like structures.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the MSA software, but you could try to use CRLF line breaks instead of LF.

I've had issues with an MS Exchange server once...